# C/C++ scraping webpage with curl after javascript has been executed

Tags: javascript, dom, curl

I know something of C/C++ and i'm trying to get the odds data from this page:
http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/italy/serie-a/inter-verona-UcNLlbb1/#odds with cURL;
i've managed to save the webpage source but my datas aren't there.Instead,if i check the odds with the "inspect element"of the browser i can see them in the DOM.So how can i catch the information i need after javascript has been executed?
Thank for the help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: _“So how can i catch the information i need after javascript has been executed?”_ – for that you would first of all get the code into an environment that does build a DOM and executes JS on it … which cURL does not.